# res.end(result) doesn't display the result on my web page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

Calling `res.end(result)` doesn't display the result on my web page, it is just displayed on the console when I call `console.log('result ' + result)`.

this is my nodejs code:

```
 const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    var url = require('url');
    var Web3 = require('web3');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });

            if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            } else {
                web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://54.00.00.00:3010"));
            }

            if (web3.isConnected()) {

                var abi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"id","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getData","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Achats","outputs":[{"name":"aName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"aId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"aDate","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"aValue","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"id","type":"uint256"},{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"iid","type":"uint256"},{"name":"date","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setData","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]');
                TestContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
                contractInstance = TestContract.at('0xc08f46fff9fcf082a0d1cebbcc464ca141d2b7d7');

                if (q.opt == 'get' && typeof q.index != "undefined") {
                    contractInstance.getData.call(parseInt(q.index), {
                        from: '0x3e10889Ef5066C1428ECaf8580aD4EFd50F8Cf7B'
                    }, function(error, result) {
                        console.log('error ' + error);
                        console.log('result ' + result);
                        res.end(result);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        app.listen(3000, function() {
            console.log('Yep... on 3000 !')
        })
```

i have been trying "res.end(result)" inside and outside of the function 'getData' but the same problem, nothing displayed on the web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a **tough** nut, but I think I got it.

See [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/634) and [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set) and [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) for how to set headers in Express and how to send data in Express. You are mixing Node's `res`/`req` with Express' `res`/`req`. Don't do that. Express wraps the Node-objects and works slightly different, e.g. it takes care about the correct headers for you.

This is what you are doing: Using `writeHead()`, you set the headers. Then, you use `.end()` with the wrong argument-type: `res.end()` [will only accept `string`s or `Buffer`s](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) as data (first error). When you change to `.send()`, that method takes care of setting the correct headers, but you had already done that manually, so you set the headers twice and you should not do that so *boom* (second error).

Solution is to remove this:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
});
```

... and then use `res.send(result)` to send your data.

As a side note, I would *love* to know how you are running your app and not getting error logs, because they were all over the place when I tried to build a verifiable example. Verbose error logs are sometimes worth more than the code that created them. This is one of those "sometimes".

Comment: Thank you so much for your help,It's finally working.

Answer (score 0):

could you try the following thing:

```
    res.write(result);
    res.end()
```

res is a `stream` so you need to write your result in `res` and then `end` it

have a nice day !

Comment: what did you received as result ?

Comment: On the console: Error: write after end.
On the web page: nothing!

Comment: normally that's happened because the result is to big, may be you should try the following just to be sure : return new Promise.resolve(() => { res.write(result); }).then(() => { res.end(); });

Answer (score 0):

Well, you only send a response back if `web3.isConnected()` and `q.opt == 'get' && typeof q.index != "undefined"`. Could be that one of those conditions do not hold.

Comment: the result was displayed on the console, that mean the two conditions works!

Comment: Can you show us what this printed result looks like. I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: result 0x6d6f756e69720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,1,0x5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,5

Comment: the function getData read the data inserted by the smart contract on the blockchain

Comment: I created a minimal version of this and returned the result successfully. 

1. Do you get any error on the console after res.end()? If so, please post
2. Try res.send instead of res.end
3. What version of node are you using?

Comment: I don't get any error on the console after res.end().
nodejs v8.6.0.

Comment: [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/sellomkantjwa/c685bca45afea1aacf0b909fcb0917ee) Basically cut out all web3 interaction .